# ¿Cómo puedo crear que el nombre de un objeto sea el valor de una variable dentro de un bucle?

Tags: java

Hola estoy trabajando en java y quiero hacer diagrama de gantt lo que me implica agregar distintas task y esas quiero traerlas de base de datos por ello eso uso el while pero quiero hacer una task diferente por cada iteracion porque si no obvio me las sustituye si le dejo solo un nombre, por ello queria saber alguna sugerencia de como podria cambiar el valor del nombre del objeto dentro del bucle, o sea en cada vuelta que se de tenga un nombre distinto, pense en un contador pero no funciono, alguna sugerencia?

[image]

Comment: Una lista.. un diccionario.. un hashmap.. todas esas son formas de guardar en una variable, muchas variables...

Comment: Tal cual, en cada iteración crea una nueva variable y al final del ciclo agrégala a un ArrayList... Al final del ciclo tendrás el ArrayList lleno de las Task que hayas creado

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el código como texto y no como imágen. Asi es más fácil ayudarte